# Best way to define constant in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, design-patterns, architecture, coding-style

Which of below 2 method is better to declare constant/config driven variables in asp.net from coding standing perspective, from architecture perspective.

Type1-

```
class Constants
{
    public static string ConnectionString
    {
        get
        {
            //Get the connection string value from web.config
            if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString"] != null)
            {
                return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString"];
            }
            else
            {
                return string.Empty;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Type 2-

```
class Constants
{
    public static string ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString"] != null ?
                                                ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString"] : string.Empty;
}
```

Is there any better way to do? Is it better to use *property* or use a *public variable*?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, the null-coalescing operator makes this a *lot* simpler.

Next, assuming `ConfigurationManager.AppSetting["ConnectionString"]` doesn't change over time, you could use:

```
// TODO: Rename this...
class Constants 
{
    private static readonly string connectionString;
    public static string ConnectionString { get { return connectionString; } }

    static Constants()
    {
        ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString"] ?? "";
    }
}
```

Or just use a property fetching it every time - a simpler version of your 
first code:

```
// TODO: Rename this...
class Constants 
{
    public static string ConnectionString
    {
         get { return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString"] ?? ""; }
    }
}
```

With C# 6 the property is even slicker:

```
// TODO: Rename this...
class Constants 
{
    public static string ConnectionString =>
        ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString"] ?? "";
}
```

The choice of whether to evaluate the `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString"]` expression or to use a cached field is unlikely to make much difference - but I *would* recommend using a property instead of a public field, as that means you can change the implementation later (e.g. to change its laziness) with no worries about backward compatibility.